# How can I rename a file containing "&" in its name in kubuntu using Dolphin or terminal?

Tags: command-line, kubuntu, files, dolphin

I have many mp3 files in my external ubuntu hdd (ext4 file system), but some files contains a "&" in their name, then Dolphin can't rename those files, and I can't move these files anywhere else too. I think it's due to the "&" in their names.

Does anyone know how to fix that please?

Comment: What error did you get? Try `mmv -n "*&amp*" "#1#2"`

Comment: If true that would be a very silly bug in dolphin which you should report to its authors so they fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Krename**

http://www.krename.net

> What is KRename ?
>
> KRename is a powerful batch renamer for KDE. It allows you to easily
>   rename hundreds or even more files in one go. The filenames can be
>   created by parts of the original filename, numbering the files or
>   accessing hundreds of informations about the file, like creation date
>   or Exif informations of an image.

Ubuntu packages: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=krename&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all

Dolphin - Right click the files > Actions > Rename with KRename

KRename has 'Find and Replace'...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the terminal, just escape the `&` character with a backslash. So to rename file `&test` to `test` do `mv \&test test`.

Comment: ok, here is the file name : Barinjaka &amp;Khelene - Ka se malisa [Official Audio].mp3, and i wish to remove the &amp, so i tryed this in terminal : sudo mv "Barinjaka &amp;Khelene - Ka se malisa [Official Audio].mp3" "Barinjaka Khelene - Ka se malisa [Official Audio].mp3" but it throws me an error

Comment: @Irrmich why are you using sudo and what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

I did this in my terminal (not kubuntu, but that shouldn't matter):

I created a file to play with:

```
kai@owncloud:~$ touch "Mike&ampThe Mecanics.mp3"
```

here you are:

```
kai@owncloud:~$ ls -la
total 27188
(...) 
-rw-r--r--  1 kai  kai         0 Jan  4 19:35 Mike&ampThe Mecanics.mp3
kai@owncloud:~$
```

Then I renamed it like this:

```
kai@owncloud:~$ mv Mike\&ampThe\ Mecanics.mp3 "Mike and the Mechanics.mp3"
```

Here is the result:

```
kai@owncloud:~$ ls -la
total 27188
(...)
-rw-r--r--  1 kai  kai         0 Jan  4 19:35 Mike and the Mechanics.mp3
kai@owncloud:~$
```

Does this solve your question?

HTH

Kai aka Cyoux

Comment: Thank you, but It did not rename the file yet :(